# Python: Rearrange categorical dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, categorical-data

I have a data frame looking like this:

```
Subject  Student ID
Math     304
Math     506
...      ...
History  304
History  402
...      ...
English  506
English  402
```

A subject can have several students, but every student has two subjects only. I want to rearrange the data frame in a way that it looks like this, where the subject order does not matter:

```
Student ID  Subject1  Subject2 
304         Math      History
506         Math      English
402         History   English
```

I tried already pivot_values, but it requires a value field. Any idea? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given `df`:

```
In [83]: df
Out[83]: 
   Subject  Student ID
0     Math         304
1     Math         506
2  History         304
3  History         402
4  English         506
5  English         402
```

Create a column number using [`groupby/cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html). This numbers the elements in each group starting at 0:

```
In [84]: df['col'] = df.groupby('Student ID').cumcount()

In [85]: df
Out[85]: 
   Subject  Student ID  col
0     Math         304    0
1     Math         506    0
2  History         304    1
3  History         402    0
4  English         506    1
5  English         402    1
```

Then you can [pivot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
In [91]: result = df.pivot(index='Student ID', columns='col', values='Subject')

In [92]: result.columns = 'Student' + (result.columns+1).astype(str)

In [93]: result
Out[93]: 
           Student1 Student2
Student ID                  
304            Math  History
402         History  English
506            Math  English
```

---

Or, as [cmaher points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48735310/python-rearrange-categorical-dataframe/48735371?noredirect=1#comment84470238_48735371), the same could be accomplished more tidily using `add_prefix`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Student ID': [304, 506, 304, 402, 506, 402],
    'Subject': ['Math', 'Math', 'History', 'History', 'English', 'English']})
df['col'] = df.groupby('Student ID').cumcount()+1
result = df.pivot(index='Student ID', columns='col', values='Subject')
result = result.add_prefix('Subject')
print(result)
```

yields the same result as above.

Comment: OP is looking for the column prefixes to be `Subject{#}`, and so you could accomplish the pivot+rename all in one go with `df.pivot(...).add_prefix('Subject')`

Comment: @cmaher: Thanks for the improvement.